# Best practice for choosing a directory where to store Lucene index in a webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, lucene, subdirectory

I'm having some pickle with indexing in Lucene: if I try to use a WEB-INF subfolder for storing indexes, the next time I redeploy my project on Tomcat the index is gone, so I kinda solved my problem using a direct subfolder, even though I can't figure out where this folder is located, but I know it exists since searching and other Lucene tasks work.

This is the code I use:

```
public void index(SomeClass someObj) {

    try {
            index = FSDirectory.open(new File("./index"));
            IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(version, analyzer);        
            config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
            writer = new IndexWriter(index, config);

            addDoc(someObj);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            closeAll(writer);
        }
}
```

Is there any best practice to pull this off and, in this case, where is the index?

Comment: Tomcat's working directory is defined by your startup script. It is most likely `CATALINA_BASE`.

Comment: To answer your second question: **no**. It most definitely is not good practice to scatter files randomly around a production server without any regard for where they might end up. In fact, there is absolutely no guarantee that the CWD is writeable in the general case. It would be better to have a [`context-param`](http://www.leveluplunch.com/blog/2014/08/18/migrating-to-servlet-3-context-parameter-spring/) configured, pointing to a known good, writeable location.

Comment: I found out the folder where index is stored is a subfolder of eclipse directory. My project requires a local subfolder where to store files, so I thought WEB-INF/ would be perfect, but Tomcat deletes my index when redeploying. I'll try with your suggestion.